Do higher types in HoTT provide mathematical structures beyond ZFC?
I've been reading Andrej Bauer's blog post on "Univalent foundations subsume classical mathematics," which explains how Univalent Foundations and Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT) extend classical mathematics by incorporating types stratified by homotopy-theoretic complexity. The post discusses that logic and sets are seen as lower-level types in this extended framework, but it also introduces higher types such as groupoids and beyond.
My question pertains to the necessity and utility of these higher types in HoTT:

Redundancy concern: In traditional set theory, particularly within Zermelo-Fraenkel (ZF) or Zermelo-Fraenkel with the Axiom of Choice (ZFC), we are able to construct a vast array of mathematical structures. Given this capability, what additional structures or benefits do higher types in HoTT (beyond logic and sets) provide? Are they not redundant since every mathematical construction achievable in HoTT seems also constructible in ZFC?

Unique constructions: Are there specific examples of mathematical structures that cannot be constructed within the ZF or ZFC framework but can be realized using the higher types in HoTT? If so, what are these structures, and how do higher types facilitate their construction?


Thank you for your insights.

As someone almost completely ignorant of type theory, my understanding is that we have an array of equiconsistency/interpretability results between set theories and type theories which imply that anything one can do, the other can do better. (mama mia!) But I would be interested to hear from someone less ignorant.

On (2), it's always worth considering the constraints of the underlying logical framework; ZFC is first-order, and there are several classes of structures which aren't first-order-izable. The "necessity and utility of these higher types" is not specific to HoTT.

I find the following analogy helpful: Comparing HoTT and ZFC is akin to comparing two different programming languages. In any sufficiently powerful programming language, you can do anything that you can do in any other language. Nevertheless, different programming languages have different merits. Some goals are easier to achieve in one language than another, and some kinds of bugs are more likely to occur in one language than another. So "redundancy" and "uniqueness" are in some sense beside the point.

@AlecRhea See for example Mariano Carneiro's master's thesis (it deals with Lean and not HoTT, but I think it is still pertinent). Roughly speaking, it shows that Lean is "equivalent" to ZFC + infinitely many inaccessibles.

The blog post was written in the context of HoTT having just come out and some people were assuming it was a form of hard constructivism (see the mailing list discussions linked to in the blog post), so I tried to explain that:

HoTT is agnostic with respect to excluded middle and the axiom of choice. One can assume these principles if so desired, and thereby incorporate set-level classical mathematics.

In HoTT the usual conception of set appears naturally as one level of a richer hierarchy of types. In this sense HoTT is a generalization of set theory. Moreover, the hierarchy is quite relevant to mathematical practice and has significant explanatory power.


Regarding the second point, note that it is not at all unusual to have sets appear in a larger universe. For example, every Grothendieck topos contains sets as a full subcategory, as well as any realizability topos.
The two foundations, ZFC and HoTT, paint different pictures of how mathematics can be organized, they serve different purposes, and they are used diffrently (see Penelope Maddy's What Do We Want a Foundation to Do?).
To demonstrate the difference, let us consider the circle. There are several mathematical manifestations of the idea:

The circle as a raw set $C$ of all points in a plane at unit distance from the origin.

The circle as a topological space $(C, \tau)$, with the standard topology $\tau$.

The circle $(\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = 1\}, 1, {}^{-1}, {\times})$ as the multiplicative subgroup of non-zero complex numbers.


The above manifestations are constructed in ZFC from sets as structure, as indicated above.
In HoTT we can also define all the manifestations in the exact way, as structures. But in addition, there is a fourth manifestation of the circle: the homotopical circle $S^1$ that is built as a higher-inductive type. This type is not the result of any set-theoretic construction carried out in HoTT.
One can of course build a model of HoTT in ZFC and observe that the homotopical circle $S^1$ is an object in this model, namely a certain Kan simplicial set, therefore it is the result of a set-theoretic construction carried out in ZFC.
I would hope that the above remarks are completely obvious. And let me be explicit: I do not think that one foundation is "better" than the other.
Now, let me finally address OP's questions.
The way I understand the first questions is this: what are the higher types appearing in HoTT good for if they already can be constructed from sets? I hope the above discussion clears this up. So long as we work inside HoTT, there are going to be types that are not sets, not can they be constructed from sets. The homotopical circle is an example.
The second question asks about structures that exist in HoTT but not in ZFC. Again, we can use the homotopical circle $S^1$ as an example. This is a pointed type, with a base point $b : S^1$, such that the monoid of all maps $S^1 \to S^1$ that fix $b$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ (in HoTT paralance we would say that the loop space of $S^1$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}$). No set has this property, for cardinality reasons.
And let me reiterate: of course one can build groupoids in ZFC and observe that there is a pointed groupoid whose loop space is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}$. However, this does not falsify the claim that in HoTT $S^1$ exhibits a phenomenon that no set can.

But non-Euclidean geometry is more flexible than its Euclidean counterpart, it just depends on what your intuition says a ‘triangle’ should be… ;^). More seriously this is a very interesting post; could you elaborate a bit on how the circle realized in type theory ‘isn’t equivalent’ to the one we can realize through the standard set-theoretical constructions? I find synthetic approaches to geometry appealing; is this maybe equivalent to the synthetic differential geometry approach using topoi formulated in a set theoretical universe?

The synthetic circle constructed as a HIT is a (proper) groupoid, while the "analytic" circle constructed as a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is, well, a set, so they are not equivalent. AFAIK real-cohesive HoTT offers a way to link the two constructions together. (Also note the incredible difference in complexity between the two: the circle HIT can be defined in two lines, while the analytic circle requires a working definition of the real numbers...)

@AlecRhea: I am not sure how to explain it succinctly. Perhaps like this. Sets can be seen as a subcategory of topological spaces, namely the discrete spaces (also the indiscrete ones, but that's not important right now). Therefore, if one defined the circle as the set of all points at unit distance from the origin, that will be a discrete space that is not homeomorphic to the usual circle. No construction that passes through set theory can ever produce a non-discrete space in this way. This situation is analogous to what happens in HoTT.

@Andrej: Isn't this just cherrypicking an interpretation to make the argument? This is like saying that since I can encode strings as vectors in Javascript, they are inherently distinct from integers. Even though that residing in your memory, even a vector is just a big number...

@AsafKaragila: what I am trying to get across (but not very well) is that building a model $M_X$ of foundation $X$ in foundation $Y$ doesn't really count as "doing $X$-things in $Y$". It's "doing $X$-things in $M_X$". Abstraction matters, also in your javascript example: vectors may appear as big numbers outside Javascript, but so long as we work in Javascript, we don't have direct access to those numbers. (And also, they're really voltages in a digital circuit.)

(You're just making an argument in favour of assembly programming here...)

I am most definitely not.

Anyhow, I made my reply to the imaginary objection more explicit, as it seems that I am being misuderstood.

The programming analogue of the objection would be that Haskell is redundant because you can compile it to assembly.

@NaïmFavier As someone who learned to code in Haskell and Python in the last year (algos/neural networks for day trading) I was amazed at how useful my experience with set theory was, partucularly with haskell — set builder notation is built into the syntax!

There's a simpler example of a structure that exists in HoTT but not ZFC: the natural numbers, because doing things in a model of PA built in ZFC is not the same thing as doing things in ZFC. At all.

More seriously, I don't think the line between "working in an interpretation of a theory" and just defining things is as solid as you're acting like it is, and "if you define things you're not working in ZFC" seems ridiculous. The core difference here isn't "HoTT has $S^1$ and ZFC doesn't", it's that HoTT has $S^1$ as a primitive object, while ZFC uses a more complicated encoding. The appropriate equivalent of HoTT's "type" in ZFC is just a rather long definition, and by replacing it with "set" you're instead looking at a different statement that's not true in HoTT either.

And the existence of the interpretation means that HoTT doesn't prove any more than ZFC (plus inaccessibles) does about sets, so in that sense it's not adding anything. Even if you accept that it has more structures than ZFC does, these structures don't tell us anything new about the things ZFC already had; even if a proof about sets is first discovered in HoTT, it follows immediately that a proof also exists in ZFC with enough inaccessibles.

To pull from the programming analogy, I agree that writing code in Common Lisp is very different from writing code in assembly. Even if the end result of the CL code is the same exact code. But this comes down to your point of view on mathematics. Are we proving the existence of algorithms and programs, or are we writing code? If it is the former, then how does CL and Asm differ?

@AsafKaragila I don't know about you, but I'm proving theorems by writing code, and HoTT makes this pleasant and intellectually satisfying.

@NaïmFavier: I'm glad for you. I'm proving theorems by writing proofs. I enjoy programming, and I enjoy doing maths the way I do it. I'd say it's a hobby, but I do have a permanent job as a mathematician and programming is just a side hobby. If you don't mind, I'll keep doing it this way.

@AndrejBauer Sorry for the naive question, but aren't you just forgetting to specify the topology in the set-theoretic construction of the circle?  You can't ask about homeomorphisms regarding a bare collection of points.

@MonroeEskew: in that example sets are (implicitly) embedded into the category of topological spaces as discrete spaces. I'm not saying it's the "right' way to do things, I am just trying to explain by analogy why in HoTT you can't use sets to define $S^1$. It's like trying to define the usual topological circle by performing constructions on discrete topological spaces.

Why do people feel like they need to defend set theory?

@pastebee: Both ZFC and HoTT have the natural numbers, directly, without any model-theoretic acrobatics. So I don't see why you claim that ZFC doesn't have the natural numbers.

Given the discussion in the comments, I rewrote my answer in the hope of expressing myself more clearly. I would also like to point out that I answered the technical qustions asked by the OP. If the OP thinks I answered the wrong questions, or misunderstood the questions, then it's their turn to try to explain what they're asking.

Thank You for kind answer, you didnt misunderstood the question

Andrej, I don't know about other people. But when you go like "Ugh, I'm gonna get comments about this being a thing, because I choose to present my argument in a specific way" it elicit responses, exactly of the kind you're anticipating. Nobody feels the need to defend ZFC. I think I'm just a bit confused with the exasperated tone, and I imagine other people are too.

@AndrejBauer About your example of the homotopical circle, I am pushed to ask, what do you mean by “all”? What do you mean by “map”, and is it synonymous with “function”? We clearly do different kinds of math, but this example doesn’t seem to jive with “classical” or “ordinary” math from my humble perspective.

@MonroeEskew: Map and function are synonymous, functions $A \to B$ coincide with functional relations. "All" means $∀$ as in first-order logic, as you would expect.  So long as we only observe sets (types of  homotopy level 0), we see something like Zermelo's bounded set theory. But the homotopical circle $S^1$  has level $1$, so it's better to think of it as the groupoid with one point and $\mathbb{Z}$-many "abstract" loops on it. We cannot show that $S^1$ has two distinct points, but it isn't equivalent to a singleton either (because of the loops).
